# Refresh token in Angular 4 for multiple api calls

Tags: angular, access-token, angular-services

I am trying to implement refresh token concept in my web app.

In page refresh i am calling 4 API's and when access-token expires am calling back-end to get a new access-token based on refresh-token.

So in my case am able to get the new access-token but again unable to trigger the 4 API calls until unless am doing page refresh manually or reload the page from service. But i don't want to reload the page and want the API calls to be done without knowing the end user.

Give some suggestion or some idea to do this.

Comment: You can call the services in `subcsribe` of your token update call. It would be easy to suggest if you could share code sample.

Comment: Do you have some code of what you did til now?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Angular HttpInterceptor to solve your problem. see snippet below.

```js
@Injectable()
export class KgRequestInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  authenticationService: MyAuthenticationService;
  snackbarService: KgSnackbarService

  constructor(private injector: Injector) { }

  addBearerAndHeaders(req: HttpRequest<any>, token: string, overwrite?: boolean): HttpRequest<any> {
    reqHeaders = reqHeaders.set("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + token);
    return req.clone({ headers: reqHeaders });
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpSentEvent | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpProgressEvent | HttpResponse<any> | HttpUserEvent<any>> {
    this.authenticationService = this.authenticationService ? this.authenticationService : this.injector.get<MyAuthenticationService>(MyAuthenticationService);
    return next.handle(this.addBearerAndHeaders(req, this.authenticationService.accessToken)).pipe(
      catchError((error, cought) => {
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          switch ((<HttpErrorResponse>error).status) {
            case 400:
              return this.handle400Error(error);
            case 401:
              return this.handle401Error(req, next);
            case 403:
              return this.handle403Error(error);
            default:
              return _throw(error);
          }
        } else {
          return _throw(error);
        }
      })

    )
  }

  handle401Error(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    if (!this.isRefreshingToken) {
      this.tokenSubject.next(null);
      this.isRefreshingToken = true;
      console.log("isRefreshingToken", this.isRefreshingToken);


      // Reset here so that the following requests wait until the token
      // comes back from the refreshToken call.
      this.authenticationService = this.authenticationService ? this.authenticationService : this.injector.get<KgAuthenticationService>(KgAuthenticationService);
      this._location = this._location ? this._location : this.injector.get<Location>(Location);

      return this.authenticationService.renewToken().pipe(
        switchMap((newToken: string) => {
          if (newToken) {
            console.log("newToken Recieved:", newToken);

            this.tokenSubject.next(newToken);
            this.authenticationService.storeRenewedToken(newToken);
            return next.handle(this.addBearerAndHeaders(req, newToken, true));
          }

          // If we don't get a new token, we are in trouble so logout.
          //return this.logout();
        }),
        catchError(error => {
          // If there is an exception calling 'refreshToken', bad news so logout.
          //return this.logout();
        }),
        finalize(() => {
          this.isRefreshingToken = false;
          console.log("isRefreshingToken", this.isRefreshingToken);
        })
      );
    } else {
      return this.tokenSubject.pipe(
        filter(token => token != null),
        take(1),
        switchMap(token => {
          console.log("newtoken:", token.substr(token.length - 20, token.length - 1))
          return next.handle(this.addBearerAndHeaders(req, token, true));
        })
      )
    }
  }

  handle400Error(error) {
    if (error && error.status === 400 && error.error && error.error.error === 'invalid_grant') {
      // If we get a 400 and the error message is 'invalid_grant', the token is no longer valid so logout.
      return this.logoutUser();
    }

    return _throw(error);
  }

  handle403Error(error) {
    if (error.status === 403) { }
    return _throw(error);
  }
}
```

good article about this is at https://www.intertech.com/Blog/angular-4-tutorial-handling-refresh-token-with-new-httpinterceptor/

Comment: This will not work, if there are multiple requests to get handled after refresh token. after refresh token, it will handle one request and other requests will not be handled.

Comment: @RishabhShah it will work thanks to tokenSubject. The first request will start refresh procedure, all next requests will wait for a token to be available: this.tokenSubject.pipe(filter(token => token != null), take(1)....

Comment: This does not seem to work, `renewToken` never appears to execute.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario better is use switchMap
when you have one Observable and you need to grab something from another request and return a different Observable, you can use SwitchMap:
https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-switchmap-operator/

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._moviesDataService.getShowtimes()
        .switchMap(res => { 
            const id = Object.keys(res[0].showtimes)[0]; // assuming you have one element in your array and you want the first id from showtimes
            return this.getMovies(id); // assuming, you have a separate method that returns the movies
        })
        .subscribe(res => this.results = res)
}
```